# Typo3 (6.2.4) Extbase / Fluid / Error Handling: Strange index of related objects

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I've got an object "Laeufer" which can have "Sponsoren" (1:n). For the "Sponsoren" I've got different required input fields like

```
<input class="form-control sponsorBetrag" name="tx_lhsponsorenlauf_p1registrierung[laeufer][sponsoren][0][betrag]" type="text">
```

But when I submit the form, the property path looks like **sponsoren.00000000497382d100007fe050b66fc0.betrag** not **sponsoren.0.betrag** which would I expect. As well the field not getting the error class "myerror". Any ideas?

FLUID

```
<f:form.textfield errorClass="myerror" property="sponsoren.0.betrag" class="form-control sponsorBetrag" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely used `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage` for your property. This is similar to the `\SplObjectStorage` and does not use numeric indexes for the internal storage array, but hashes the objects it is going to store and uses this hashed object as index for it. You can however work around that and use `$this->view->assign('sponsoren', $sponsoren->toArray());` in your controller to assign a real array to your view, instead of the ObjectStorage.

Second, your field isn't getting the error class, because you do not use a ViewHelper. Therefore Fluid doesn't care about your input at all. I would suggest to use `<f:form.textfield property="betrag" />` in your template instead of a self-written input.

EDIT:

As far as I know, the usage of an OjectStorages Sub-Property as a distinct field, instead of having a select field, is not possible with TYPO3 6.2.
It may be, that your Domain Model Architecture is wrong though, if you need to have form fields for distinct elements of your ObjectStorage. If you have a sponsor-object that is a specific one, you should use a distinct property for this one, instead of have it in a list of sponsors.

If you want to have an edit form for single sponsors, do it like this

```
<f:for each="{sponsors}" as="sponsor">
    <f:form action="update" controller="Sponsor" object="{sponsor}" name="sponsor">
        <f:form.textfield property="betrag" errorClass="myerror" class="form-control sponsorBetrag" />
    ...
        <f:form.submit value="Update sponsor" />
    </f:form>
</f:for>
```

and create a controller that can update single sponsors.

Comment: Oh sorry that was the html code. I'm using the viewhelper: <f:form.textfield errorClass="isInvalid" property="sponsoren.0.betrag" class="form-control sponsorBetrag" />. The form should create new "sponsoren" for the "laeufer"

Comment: Can you update your question then and provide the correct information?

Comment: Yes shure, I updated it. The hash of the propertypath is always the same? I have to know it for translation.

Comment: okay its not always the same, so I don't know how to translate it

Comment: Please read my answer, contents of the ObjectStorage are not supposed to be distinguishable. If you need to create translation labels for the single sponsors in your ObjectStorage, you need to have distinct fields for each sponsor in your Model